# Relation does not exist error with pg-promise and postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am using pg-promise on Node 7.2.1 with PostgreSQL 9.4.  I am using the code below to connect to the PostgreSQL server:

```
// pg-promise connection elements.

// Database initialization options.
const pg_options = {
    // Initialization options.
};

// Create an instance of the pg-promise library.
const g_pg_promise = require('pg-promise')(pg_options);

// Connection string for a local connection to the 'summarize' database.
const g_pg_connection =
{
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'db_stats',
    user: 'db_user',
    password: '{password here}'
}

// Connect to the database.
const g_pg_database = g_pg_promise(g_pg_connection);

// Expose the database object globally.  The database object should only
//  be instantiated once and then shared.
module.exports = {
    g_pg_promise: g_pg_promise,
    g_pg_database: g_pg_database
};
```

I know the connection parameters are valid because I use the exact same values in other non-Node.JS apps to connect to the same PostgreSQL server.  I also know that **db_stats** is a valid database name.  I have worked with that database for quite a while with other non Node.JS apps and via pgAdmin 3.x.

However, when I attempt to connect using pg-promise I get the following error:

```
error: relation "db_stats" does not exist
```

I did see the SO post below:

[Unable to query PostgreSQL database in NodeJS using pg-promise - "relation does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783836/unable-to-query-postgresql-database-in-nodejs-using-pg-promise-relation-does)

But that post did not make sense to me because I believe Vitaly, the author of pg-promise, was telling the poster that he did not have a **table** called **users**, when it looks to me that the poster was trying to access the **database** called **users** and he definitely had a database with that name.

In any case, I **definitely** have a database named *db_stats* so I'm not sure why I am getting this error.  How can I solve this?

Comment: The error is *not* talking about a *database* named `"db_stats"`, but a *relation* (either a *table* or a *view*) with that name. That is, `db_stats` most probably appears in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` query.

Comment: @joanolo Thanks that was it.  I was so focused on the connection statement that I didn't think about that.  If you would like to upscale your comment to a reply, I'd like to "accept" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error: relation "db_stats" does not exist

The error you get from PostgreSQL is not referring to a *database* named `"db_stats"`, but to a *relation* (either a *table* or a *view*) with that name.

That is, `db_stats` most probably appears in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` query (although it may be also a `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...).

There is neither a `db_stats` table nor a view in your database. Or, maybe, it exists, but it exists in a schema that is *not* part of your current [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

To find out, check two things:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_name = 'db_stats' ;
```

If there is a table there... you already know which schema(s) contains it/them.
Then, make sure that this schema is part of your `search_path` by means of:

```
SHOW search_path ;
```

You might have to execute this SQL statements by adding the adequate code to your application, and use a debugger to check what's returned in that environment.