# postgres: 'relation "users" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, pg

All tests were passing before, but I updated a couple packages and now a bunch of tests are failing because the tests can't find any of the tables in my local/testing database (issue is not just with the `users` table but with all tables in my db). The package updates happened via Dependabot security fixes, and when the tests were run on the TravisCI server they all passed. Because everything was passing, I already merged the updates into the development branch. Nothing was failing until I pulled the branch and tried to run tests locally.

I can see the database and all the tables it can't find in pgAdmin. I have tried:

- uninstalling/reinstalling Postgres
- dropping/recreating the database and re-running migrations in `knex` to recreate all tables
- re-installing `pg` and `knex`
- ensuring that the schema is in the `search_path` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123348/relation-does-not-exist-error-with-pg-promise-and-postgresql)
- ensuring that my psql user has schema-level privileges as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938476/relation-users-does-not-exist-postgresql)

Any other ideas what I could try?

Comment: this is usuially, because you are connected to the wrong database

Comment: @nbk Do you have suggestions about how I would confirm if there is an issue with the connection?

Comment: when i run `\conninfo` at the `psql` prompt it shows me the expected user and database name, but i don't know how to confirm if that's how my tests are connection. i do see the correct username and database name in the `.env` variables that are populating my `knexfile.js` but if there's somewhere else I should check let me know.

Comment: knexjs has a configuration file, which should contain all information to the connection, see the manual how to start knexjs and postgres has some information functions you can use to determine if the server is correct or the database, when we are at it https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-info.html

Comment: @nbk yes, the `config/knex.js` pulls its config from `knexfile.js`, which is populated by variables in `.env`. everything in those files looks correct and nothing in any of them has changed recently -- this app has been live for several years and this problem just started yesterday so i don't think it's a base configuration issue. any other ideas about why the tests might not be able to find the tables?

Comment: If the configuration are correct and every postgres comand shows you that you on the correct database, you should chec if the user has rights. but istill think that you are conncetd twi different databses, which should show when you run the linked postgres comands

Comment: @nbk do you know how i would run that command in my test file? i'm using the `pg` node-postgres package but if i try to run `pg.current_database()` it says that function does not exist. i can see the database at the `psql` command line prompt and in pgadmin, but i'm not sure how to figure out what my test file is trying to connect to